# Problems running executable-jar in Windows 7 in different countries

Tags: java, batch-file, character-encoding, executable-jar

I have created an executable jar file long back. I use to run it using the bat file command '**java  -jar -Xms3048M esc.jar**'.

This works perfectly in India and Germany, both being Windows 7 environment. But in other regions such as Japan, the program hangs. The program involves interacting with files (both read and write). From the web I learned that the encoding might vary in different regions.

So i altered my command to '**java -Dfile.encoding=Cp437 -jar -Xms3048M esc.jar**' After altering this command, again it works fine in India and Germany regions but fails in Japan. What do you think I am missing?

Since this is a legacy JAR, I can't edit the java files. Is there something that could be done to make it run in all the countries alike? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no exception? or log file to check the reason???

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ There is no issue when it works in India or Germany but has problems when it runs in Japan. There are no descent log files I can attach here. In the command prompt from which I run the bat file, **there are no exceptions thrown.**